# HQL count() with group by not returning zero/0 records

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql, hql

```
String query = "select hour(la.dateLastUpdated) as hour," 
+ "coalesce(count(la), 0) from LoginActivity la" 
+ "where la.dateLastUpdated > :date" 
+ "group by hour(la.dateLastUpdated)" 
+ "order by hour(la.dateLastUpdated)";

Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 12*60*60*1000));
```

Result I'm getting is like

```
Hour  Count
----  -----
12    1
13    3
15    4
17    11
```

But I want result like

```
Hour  Count
----  -----
12    1
13    3
14    0
15    4
16    0
17    11
```

That means the zero counts. Tried `coalesce` but it's not working. Any probable hql query to get expected result? Native query also will do.

*I'm using PostgreSql database

Comment: Fill in the blanks programmatically, after you executed the query.

Answer (score 2):

If the record you want (for example `Hour = 14`) does not exist in your `LoginActivity` table, how can you expect it to show up in your resultset?

I assume that you want to list every hour of the day and get record counts based on that; if this is the case then

1. You need a dictionary-like structure that includes every hour of the day to begin with,
2. You need to execute a `left outer join` from this structure to your resultset, joining on the field `Hour`.

Comment: Exactly. And I would like to point out that this is not an HQL / Hibernate problem, but a common behaviour of database queries.

Comment: Thanks for your thought @Erkan ! I've filled up the blanks programmatically. Do you think the overhead is large in this case?

Comment: It depends. I don't know about your application's architecture, but as a rule of thumb it is "usually" better to implement this kind of behavior on database level. This way you can reuse the result set produced.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :::

```
"Select hour(la.dateLastUpdated) as hour,  count(coalesce(la, 0)) 
from LoginActivity la  
where la.dateLastUpdated > :date 
group by hour(la.dateLastUpdated)  
order by hour(la.dateLastUpdated);"
```

Comment: yeah this wont work untill the 'hours' for which you want count as zero is present in record.As Erkan said you need to make a table with all hours needed and do left outer join to this table and than find count.

Answer (score 0):

From postgres you can get the result using this query.

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(12,24) AS s(hourdigit)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
    hour(la.dateLastUpdated) AS hour,
    coalesce(count(la), 0) 
    FROM LoginActivity la
    WHERE la.dateLastUpdated > '2014-05-05'
    GROUP BY hour(la.dateLastUpdated)
    ORDER BY hour(la.dateLastUpdated)
) AS resultdata ON resultdata.hour = s.hourdigit
```

Comment: I haven't tested it though.... It would have been better if you had given the table structure